# backbone open.window reference that.w

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, window.open

I have a window I've opened from a Backbone operation:

```
...
displayData: function() {
    var that = this;
    var id = that.passDataObj.id;
    var htmlToWrite = that.AAComment();
    if (that.windowToWriteInCreated == false) {
        that.windowToWriteInCreated = true;
        that.windowToWriteIn = window.open("popupSearchView.html", "", "menubar=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=no");
       $(that.windowToWriteIn.document.getElementById('tabs')).html("<ul>" +
                                                                        "<li>" +
                                                                            "<a href='#tabs-" + id + "'>" + id + "</a>" +
                                                                            "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>RemoveTab</span>" +
                                                                        "</li>" +
                                                                    "</ul>" +
                                                                    "<div id='tabs-" + id + "'>" +
                                                                        htmlToWrite +
                                                                    "</div>");

        that.windowToWriteIn.addEventListener('load', that.windowToWriteIn.createTabs(), true);
    } else {
       $(that.windowToWriteIn.document.getElementById('tabs')).append("<ul>" +
                                                                        "<li>" +
                                                                            "<a href='#tabs-" + id + "'>" + id + "</a>" +
                                                                            "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>RemoveTab</span>" +
                                                                        "</li>" +
                                                                    "</ul>" +
                                                                    "<div id='tabs-" + id + "'>" +
                                                                        htmlToWrite +
                                                                    "</div>");

        that.windowToWriteIn.addEventListener('load', that.windowToWriteIn.addTab(), true);
},
...
```

It calls the html code of popupSearchView.html that has the following code for it:

```
...
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui.1.11.2.min.redmond.css" />
<script src="./jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    function createTabs() {
        $('#tabs').tabs();
    }

    function addTab() {
        $('#tabs').tabs("refresh");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='tabs'>
    </div>
</body>
```

I make a call initially to create a window that will hold a jQuery-UI tab area.  It all seems to work fine, except for the fact that when I try to call the addTab function, to create another tab in the jQuery-UI tabbed window, it simply creates a new window.  I would like it to simply append to the existing 'tab' div and then refresh the tabs to display the new tab.  Is there a way I can make sure that the second call, to displayData, will append the html to the existing window to add a second tab?

I hope there is.

Comment: The code is so unreadable.. you should use a template engine. Please try to format it better and share a [mcve]

Comment: @T J - I do have template, that is the "var htmlToWrite = that.AAComment();" statement is calling, from a predefined template in the initialize of the backbone view.  Other than that, I don't believe a JSFIDDLE would work to display this, so I can't help you too much about the code being "unreadable". the displayData gets called in another part of the backbone code.  Maybe this can help.